# Как достать Cookies?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Как достать куки из браузера и сделать POST запрос на сервер?
Запрос собираюсь делать таким образом:

```
NSString *url = @"http://...";    
NSString *parameters = @"Куки";
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                                                                   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                               timeoutInterval:15.0];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"post";
    request.HTTPBody = [parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

Не мучайся и используй Alamofire. Подключаешь библиотеку и посылаешь GET запрос на сайт:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "твой_сайт") .responseJSON { response in

    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        self.jsonArray = JSON as? NSMutableArray

        self.setCoolkie = (response.response!.allHeaderFields as? [String: String])!["Set-Cookie"]!

    }
}
```

Если не хочешь использовать Alamofire, то вот пример для пост запроса:

```
func makeRequest(){

var params: AnyObject?

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "твой_сайт")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
params = ["параметры":"если они есть"]

do {
    request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params!, options: [])
} catch {
    print(error)
    request.HTTPBody = nil
}
request.setValue("\(self.setCoolkie!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Set-Cookie")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    guard data != nil else {
        print("no data found: \(error)")
        return
    }

    do {
        if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary {

                print(json);

        } else {
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            print("Error could not parse JSON 1: \(jsonStr)")
        }
    } catch let parseError {
        print("\(parseError) ")

            print("Проблемы с подключение к серверу")

    }
})

task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Я смотрю, если использовать Alamofire код становится меньше и приятнее. Но я использую AFNetworking для загрузки JSON файлов  и тд. Но Alamofire тоже позволяет это реализовать. Будет ли рационально использовать эти две библиотеки в одном проекте. И в чем преимущество Alamofire перед AFNetworking или наоборот?

Comment: Используйте AFNetworking если вы используете Objective-C, а если используете Swift, то используйте Alamofire

Comment: Точно, я сразу не заметил, что это на Swift. Можно пример подобной реализации на Objective-C?